# How do I test my RPM?

Tags: mocking, fedora, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I'm new at creating RPMs. I created -or at least tried- to create an RPM following these steps: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_a_GNU_Hello_RPM_package

I tried to test my RPM with the following command:

```
$ mock --verbose ../SRPMS/hello-2.8-1.fc20.src.rpm
```

But I get this error

> ERROR: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
>
> ERROR: The most common cause for this error is trying to run /usr/sbin/mock as an unprivileged user.
>   ERROR: Check your path to make sure that /usr/bin/ is listed before /usr/sbin, or manually run /usr/bin/mock to see if that fixes this problem.

Is there another way to test my RPM? When will I be able to do the

```
dnf install myrpmname
```

?
Please. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: That is a source rpm. You should keep going and create an actual rpm and test that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first proposal in the question is to run the mock using `/usr/bin/mock`:

```
/usr/bin/mock --verbose ../SRPMS/hello-2.8-1.fc20.src.rpm
```

The second which comes to my mind is to make sure your user is in the `mock` group and re-login:

```
usermod -a -G mock <<your username>>
```